# Redirect errors to /dev/null when greping and finding on Solaris

Tags: grep, find, solaris, io-redirection

I find myself having to play around with Solaris. I would usually redirect with `2>/dev/null` which works on Solaris in general, but not with these two ways of doing recursive "greps" on Solaris.

```
# no errors, but doesn't actually redirect "permission denieds" to /dev/null
/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep -rni test / 2>/dev/null

# errors
find / -type f -exec grep test {} + 2>/dev/null
find: bad option 2
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: How about `-s` option of `grep` to suppress errors?

Answer (score 4):

`2>/dev/null` works on Solaris just like any other Unix variant. It's a feature of the shell (error output redirection with `2>`) plus a feature that exists on everything that's even vaguely Unix-like (`/dev/null` as a universal absorber).

The behavior you describe shows that you're using a shell where `2>` is not a redirection operator. Presumably, you're using csh. The solution is [not to use csh](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/csh). Csh was the best interactive shell in the 1980s, but this isn't the 1980s anymore. There's no reason to use csh on Solaris any more than on any other Unix variant. Use ksh, or, if you want a more comfortable command line experience, zsh or bash.